# $(document).ready() and initializing jQuery at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me get this straight. According to best practice we should initialize jQuery at the bottom of the page. If we do that, any reference to the jQuery object (ie. `$` or `jQuery`) above the reference will be a null. However, as for `$(document).ready()`, the reason why this jQuery function is ever needed is when you want to delay an execution of a function after the page has loaded. This seems to be a conflict.

How do I use the functionality of `$(document).ready()` at the top of the page and still reference jQuery at the bottom of the page? I think jQuery should be initialized at the top of the page for this very reason.

Comment: You're right. You have to put your initial jQuery reference before you use $, so if you use $ at the top of the page, that's where you have to reference the library.

Comment: Yes - the efficiency advice is actually to have all javascript at the bottom of the page. You can still have the jQuery initialization as the top part of this javascript, and use $(function() {...}); AFTER that

Comment: The thing that annoys me is Telerik MVC's framework needs to reference its javascript and it's dependent frameworks (ie: jquery) at the bottom of the page for their controls to work properly.

I've decided to use window.onload() for now.

Comment: I hear you burnt1ce, but I'm suggesting: "<html><head>...</head><body>...<script src="jquery.js"></script><script>/* your script */ $(function() { ... /* your code here */ });</script></body></html>" Apologies for the terrible formatting that these comments restrict me to!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - Is $(document).ready necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/jquery-is-document-ready-necessary)

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to put your scripts at the bottom of the page for efficiency purposes, and there are no further elements (beyond `</body> and </html>`)  you wont even need to use `$(document).ready(...);`.

Placing your code at the top of the page makes sense semantically, and the loading time "savings" is negligible in most cases. It really only makes a difference when the scripts are enormous, or when the scripts are on another server that may or may not be active.

If you're live-linking jQuery, i'd suggest putting it at the bottom of the page. If you're local-linking jQuery, the top should be fine. Just make sure to use minimized code.

Comment: Wait.. what? I was under the impression that document.ready was a little more robust than sticking code at the end of the body tag.

Comment: @SkippyChalmers, `document.ready` is more robust than `body.onload`, but *both* are events that are fired when the DOM has finished parsing/executing elements on the page. If you place a script at the end of the page, you will have essentially done the same thing. The one difference will be that all scripts will have been executed before the loading callback, which could be important if the executing code relies on a library that hasn't been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `$(document).ready` below where you initialize jQuery regardless of where that is.

In reality though you should be putting all your JS at the bottom, even `$(document).ready`.

Comment: That's not very easy to do when you're writing controls.

Comment: Well you didn't mention that in the original question :P.