# Javascript script at bottom of HTML page as good as JQuery's document-ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, embedding, document-ready, document-body

In a discussion, someone argued that embedding Javascript in a `<script>` just before the `</body>` HTML tag is as good as using JQuery's document-ready. Is that true? Is it really safe in all situations for all browsers?

**Update:** Great answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438883/jquery-why-use-document-ready-if-external-js-at-bottom-of-page).

Comment: Its not "as good", its considered better practice in most cases

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005789/when-do-you-need-to-use-document-ready and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/jquery-is-document-ready-necessary

Comment: Of course it's not as good, it doesn't use enough jQuery.

Comment: more duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438883/jquery-why-use-document-ready-if-external-js-at-bottom-of-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877390/is-document-ready-necessary-if-i-put-all-my-javascript-at-the-bottom-of-the-p