# Do I need to 'document.ready()' this piece of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use freemarker to generate HTML pages on the fly for user requests. These include a link to a javascript file in the header. In this file, an array is defined. I need to assign the value of `myArray[0]` for each generated page with a different and dynamic value.

I was thinking about about adding a script in the HTML:

```
<body>
  <script>myArray[0]="MyDynamicValue";</script>
  ...
</body>
```

I am wondering whether I should execute this initialization in (for example) JQuery's document-ready? I don't think so, but I am hesitating...

Comment: The only reason you use `$(document).ready(function() {` or `$(function() {` is to ensure that the DOM is ready. So if it has no interaction with the DOM, no.

Comment: I would think no. If your array is not dependent on another element, then no, it can be constructed inline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - Is $(document).ready necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/jquery-is-document-ready-necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing about it depends on accessing the DOM, so there is no need to wait for the DOM to be ready.

(Nothing there constructs a `myArray` object though, so in the absence of anything other code, this will throw an error… but waiting for the DOM to be ready won't change that unless it coincidently also causes it to be executed after `myArray` is created.)