# Is it nessary to put all codes inside ready?

Tags: jquery

I am wondering when using Jquery, it is required to put all code inside

```
$(Docuemnt).ready(function() {
     *****
     other codes;
});
```

Comment: This question has been asked before...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/is-document-ready-necessary

Answer (score 0):

No you just need to put the code which have to be executed when the page is load, for example all the onClick function.

You can have code like this :

```
$(Docuemnt).ready(function() {
     $('.myClass').on('Click', myFunction);
});

function myFunction(event) {
   //do some stuff
}
```