# My script needs page refresh for it to run

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I load my page for the first time my script does not load, I need to refresh the page at least 3 times for it to run. How can I make my script run without a page refresh? This particular script is in BABEL.

```
'use strict';

var deg = 0;
var index = 0;

$('#' + index).css('opacity', '1');
$('.navbar').contextmenu(function () {
    return false;
});
$('.navbar').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var move = -60;
    var nextIndex = nextIndex = (index + 1) % 6;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 <= 0) {
        // wheel up
        move = 60;
        nextIndex = index  -1 < 0 ? 5 : index - 1;
    }
    $('.scroll-list').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + (deg + move) + 'deg)');
    $('#' + index).css('opacity', '0.01');
    $('#' + nextIndex).css('opacity', '1');
    index = nextIndex;
    deg = deg + move;
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.timeEnd('cache');
});
```

Comment: Wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { /* code */ });`?

Comment: Do you have cache disabled in your browser?  Where is your script added to the page?  The `<head>` or at the bottom of `<body>`?

Comment: this script is in js file and you include path of js file in html page?

Comment: Try refresh with control-F5 (ignore cache).

Comment: Your page may yet still be loading, so your script won't fire until it's fully loaded. @ChrisForrence solution is your best bet.

Comment: @zero298 my script is at the body I have tried and put in the head to check if it will work but it didn't.

Comment: @ChrisForrence it didn't work :(

Comment: @freedomn-m my point is that i need the script to run without a refresh.

Comment: Post your HTML structure including your `<script>` tag.  You have answers that assume you aren't waiting for elements to load, but that may not be the case depending on where you are adding your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $(document).ready necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/is-document-ready-necessary)

Comment: @Tutch I' am waiting 2 minutes now and it has no effect , also i have not have that much html/css for it to take so long to load.

Comment: @Angelo that's not what you've described.  You've said it doesn't run on first load (which *is* a "refresh").  If the script is cached, it may run incorrectly until the cache updates itself (after refreshing a few times).  By using ctrl-f5 once, your cache will be updated.   This may not be the issue, hence the "try" - ie use ctrl-f5 rather than just f5.  If it works, then your issue is with caching and there are ways to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And what if you wrapped your code inside a window.onload function?

```
window.onload = function() { 
  // your code
}
```

Your code will only run when the html document is "ready" and fully loaded.

Comment: plz try : $(window).on( "load", function() { ... })

Comment: the correct answer was :  window.onload = function() { ...} . For some reason the  $(window).on( "load", function() { ... }) didn't work. Could you change your answer to the correct one so i can give it to you because you basically gave me the answer and it may help someone else who has the same problem.

Comment: @Angelo update done, but also now i see the 'real' problem, you have to put the jquery script call before your code, for example just after the body opening tag. because your script is using jquery.

Answer (score 3):

You are running Javascript that depends on page elements and the javascript is executed before the elements are on the page;

Wrapp all your code inside document.ready function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var deg = 0;
var index = 0;

$('#' + index).css('opacity', '1');
$('.navbar').contextmenu(function () {
    return false;
});
$('.navbar').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var move = -60;
    var nextIndex = nextIndex = (index + 1) % 6;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 <= 0) {
        // wheel up
        move = 60;
        nextIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? 5 : index - 1;
    }
    $('.scroll-list').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + (deg + move) + 'deg)');
    $('#' + index).css('opacity', '0.01');
    $('#' + nextIndex).css('opacity', '1');
    index = nextIndex;
    deg = deg + move;
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.timeEnd('cache');
});
});
```

Wrap your code in `ready` function, so that your JavaScript executes after DOM is loaded.