# Javascript loading blocked on URL click, unless forcefully refreshed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter, url

I am working on a Flutter mobile app that launches external URLs using the url_launcher package. One of the URLs I'm working with relies on JavaScript for tracking, but the JavaScript execution is blocked when the URL is initially loaded in an external browser. However, when users manually refresh the page, JavaScript is unblocked, and the URL returns a 200 status code. This behavior is consistent across desktop and mobile browsers.

My goal is to use this URL in my Flutter app and ensure that JavaScript is activated when the URL is launched in an external browser. I would like to programmatically trigger the refresh or reload action to achieve this.

Here is the current logic I'm using to launch the URL:

```
  final uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com');
        if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
          launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        }
```

I have confirmed that JavaScript is enabled, and cookies are enabled in the external browser. The issue appears to be related to the initial page load. I also tested the URL by manually pasting it into a notepad and launching it in a Chrome browser, and the issue persisted until I tapped the reload icon.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to programmatically trigger the reload action for external URLs in a Flutter app to ensure that JavaScript is activated upon launch?

Comment: Reminder that StackOverflow expects questions to be programming related. If the URL is created by third-party and doesn't work in either desktop or mobile browsers, either (a) you will need to push back on where you got that URL to get a working one or (b) debug that URL so that it works to your expectation and explain the changes needs to the third-party provider.

Comment: Both options don't work for me. a: No response from the third party on the url b: How do I proceed with debugging? I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: There are sites/books/tutorials on how to debug javascript/web pages. Which assumes that you know what the URL/site/Javascript is supposed to do. However as you have no control of the third-party javascript/site you may want to look at [My script needs page refresh for it to run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46791887/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to get this to work by using external browser via url_launcher package. I solved it by using in-app web view's reload functionality.